# Input Source Language keeps changing on Mac OS X 10.9.2 -- how to make the computer keep my desired setting?

Tags: macos, mac, virus, input-languages

First time posting on this site so hopefully I am posting it in the right place. Apologies if not. I've been having issues with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, mid 2009). I have my input source language set as "Irish"; however, as of today any time I log in (after the computer has been shut down) the input source language has switched itself to "U.S.", and I have to go and change it back to "Irish".

I haven't changed anything major as of late. The only thing I can think of is that I accidently clicked a link in a spam email which linked to a "Linkbucks" site which then had a "skip this ad" button which again I foolishly clicked which in turn led to a JPG image of someone's Facebook. I googled "Linkbucks" and read that it is a web browser hijacker virus which can then change your settings etc.

I ran Clamx Av to see if anything of that sort was on my computer, but nothing came up. Am I just being paranoid here thinking some Linkbucks virus has infected my computer? **How do I stop the computer from constantly resetting the input language on power-off?** Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi GaelUirbeach, and welcome to Super User. I can't help you with your specific problem, but I have edited your question slightly for grammar and formatting, as well as added the *specific* question that I *believe* you were asking. Should you feel my edits changed the intent of your post in any way, feel free to **[edit]** further, or to roll back the edit (click the "edited ... ago" link, then click "rollback" next to the revision you wish to roll back to).

Comment: Thanks Michael Kjörling. Apologies for the awful grammar. It's never been my forte. The specific question you added is exactly what I wanted to know. I will bear in mind to be more specific with my questions in future. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries about the grammar. The most important part (other than making sure your question is on topic in the first place, and do what you can to find an answer on your own before posting a new question; I suggest looking through the help center if you haven't already) is to be clear and *specific,* and if it bothers someone enough, they'll come around and fix any other issues.